# How to use OpenGL fragment shader to convert RGB to YUV420

Tags: opengl

I know how to code a shader that converts planar data (YUV420 image) to packed one (RGB image) using fragment shader, yet how do I code the RGB to YUV420.
I do not need the YUV420 image for rendering but to pass it to the h264 compression code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From http://www.fourcc.org/fccyvrgb.php:

> ### RGB to YUV Conversion
>
> Y  =      (0.257 * R) + (0.504 * G) + (0.098 * B) + 16
>
> Cr = V =  (0.439 * R) - (0.368 * G) - (0.071 * B) + 128
>
> Cb = U = -(0.148 * R) - (0.291 * G) + (0.439 * B) + 128

In a OpenGL shader those constant offsets at the end need to be multiplied by 1/256. Also if you look closely this is a vector-matrix multiplication. You can express this by

```
mat4 RGBtoYUV(0.257,  0.439, -0.148, 0.0,
              0.504, -0.368, -0.291, 0.0,
              0.098, -0.071,  0.439, 0.0,
              0.0625, 0.500,  0.500, 1.0 );

YUV = RGBtoYUV * RGB;
```

Some other formulas are given at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV

Comment: Is it assumed that rgb values normalized ?

Comment: @MichaelIV: Yes, the values for R, G and B are assumed to be in the range [0; 1]. Say you're writing an OpenGL fragment shader, then color values are normalized already and you can apply the above coversion directly. Note that the code assumes linear RGB, but most images on a PC are in nonlinear sRGB color space, so you first have to convert from sRGB to RGB. Since this is a rather expensive process, modern GPUs offer a sRGB texture mode, that does fast liniearization at texel lookup. Google for "sRGB textures".

Comment: I think the crux of the question has less to do with colorspace conversion, and more with how to get the fragment shader to output planar pixels, given packed pixels.

Comment: @thinkski: With modern OpenGL you can define multiple output targets for a fragment shader. So create a shader with 3 outputs (one for Y, one for U, and one for V) and attach the layers of a 2D texture array with mipmap levels to it (you don't need the whole image pyramid). After rendering use the generate mipmap function to downsample the the result, then read the planes out of the texture layers.

Answer (score 4):

Since the YUV pixel is not packed, you shall attach multiple color buffers to the shader program (i.e. One for luminance and two for chrominance).

The sizes of the chrominance output buffers differs fromt the luminance one, due the chrominance sampling. Because this, you shall test for ARB_framebuffer_object extension. If not available you shall compute unsampled chrominance values and sample them after rendering. Note also that sampling in shader is not easy, since you have to know the source pixel position, indeed be carefull about texture coordinates.

So, create a framebuffer object, attach 3 renderbuffer objects (or textures), and declare fragment shader output variable as an array of length 3 of vec4.

Attached buffers can have a RED internal format, since they storeonly one component.

Once rendered, fetch renderbuffer data (or texture data), interleave YUV layer as needed (maybe using SSE), and you have done your job.

Maybe you want to generate unsampled chrominance values. In this case you shall sample chrominance buffers by yourself, maybe blending contiguos chrominance values.

Comment: Use textures as the chrominance FBO render attachment. Choose texture parameters in a way that only the 1st mipmaping level is used (`glTexParameter(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_{BASE,MAX}_LEVEL, 1)`) then after conversion do glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D). Voíla, you can fetch a subsampled chrominance plane using glGetTexImage2D.

Comment: I thought of different way: Use two RGB textures. One of the original size and the second of half size. I use a fragment shader to convert the RGB to YUV interleaved. Than I do a texture mapping of the YUV texture of scale 0.5 so I get the YUV image in half size. Now I need to grab the channels. I grab the Red (Y) from the full size YUV image and the Green (U) and Blue (V) from the half size to same buffer right after the Y. This way I get YUV420. Thanks for all the help.